# Replacing line breaks, leaving part of capturing group

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have some parsing issues with a csv file. Apparently, every time there's a line break, Excel sees it as a new row, despite the usage of quotation marks in the original file:

```
"1234","so,
I have more requests for this"
"12345","have a nice day"
```

Not sure if that is the right approach, but I wish to use (say) Sublime to remove all line break with no `"` after.
To do so, I used the following regex: `\n[^"]`, replacing with capturing group zero, so that in the example above, this:

```
,
I
```

Will be replaced by: `,I`.
Unfortunately, capturing group zero (`$0`) includes both the line break alongside the `I`.

1. Why is Excel not opening the file properly?
2. What am I missing in my solution?
3. How can I make this replacement work?

Thanks!

Comment: `\n(?!")` and replace with empty string. If you *import* the data to Excel, it should open fine, but when you double click, it does not always open as expected.

Comment: BTW, a csv like that opens fine in my Excel: cell `B1` has two lines of text. Maybe there's an issue with the characters? (0x13+0x10 vs just one of them?) Doing this replacement with a regex may be complex. Can this new line character be only in the last field?

Comment: Interesting @Andrew. How can I find out?

Comment: You would need some editor or viewer which tells you the exact hex value of each byte, like a Hex Editor. What if you create a new one with Notepad by typing what you posted here?

Answer (score 1):

So, using Wiktor Stribiżew's solution from the comments:

```
\n(?!")
```

Advanced me to some extent, but still had issues. Ultimately I found out the text had `+` in it, making excel see it as a, sometime never ending, formula. Once I removed it, issued resolved.

Comment: So then the input may be an invalid csv. Was that `+` not quoted?

Comment: It was! Very weird

Comment: I did some tests but couldn't reproduce the issue, I did get though an invalid function even though it was quoted. The quotes just make sure all the contents belong to one cell, but if you need some strange code to be considered string, I guess you sill need to use the `="your text"` syntax. Anyway, if you need further help with the csv you may want to update the question with the new findings.